# Does Post Channel Message Microsoft Teams Graph API works for Microsoft Teams Free User too?

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have requirement to support Microsoft Teams free user. Does Post Channel message (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/${team_id}/channels/${channel}/messages) works for Microsoft Teams free user ? If so how to delegate the permission to the User ?

Comment: Delegated(personal account) is not supported, If you have work or school account you can use the delegated mode and call the API

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT. Is there any other way to send message to the channel for the Personal account ?

Comment: You can send message to channel using Bot.Please look at [Conversation Basics with Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conversations)

Comment: Thanks @Trinetra-MSFT.